# Islam on Not saving any money

Tags: zakat, money, sadaqah

I got married to someone who has totally different views on saving/finances. I am of the view that money should be spent in moderation and saved too after giving charity/zakat. Where as my husband is of the view that there's no point of saving as Allah is the sole provider. No doubt in that indeed but what is the stance in Islam where a person isn't putting in any effort himself.

Comment: O you who have believed, fear Allah. **And let every soul look to what it has put forth for tomorrow** - and fear Allah. Indeed, Allah is Aware of what you do.(59:18)

Comment: Prophet used to save money for his family for the following year. That means if someone wants to save the maximum he should save is what's required to live through a year. Adding luxuries is always an option.